# ld: framework not found GData

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gdata

Why is Xcode saying it can't find my GData framework when I try to build the app? The GData.framework dir is in the same directory (both on the HD and in the Project navigator) as the other .frameworks (CoreData, etc.) and its also added in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" panel.

Here is the log output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/GData.framework/Versions/A/GData
Referenced from: /Users/zak/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/897A560D-3AD5-42BE-958B-84DEA45A8F0E/MyApp.app/MyApp
Reason: image not found
```

And here is the full issue report:

```
Ld /Users/zak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fcvdbuanprmqvjafgwsuxlokvpsd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp normal i386
cd /Users/zak/Dropbox/xcodeProjects/MyApp
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/zak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fcvdbuanprmqvjafgwsuxlokvpsd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/zak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fcvdbuanprmqvjafgwsuxlokvpsd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/zak/Dropbox/xcodeProjects/MyApp/.. -filelist /Users/zak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fcvdbuanprmqvjafgwsuxlokvpsd/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyApp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework CoreData -framework UIKit -framework GData -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/zak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fcvdbuanprmqvjafgwsuxlokvpsd/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

ld: framework not found GData
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**EDIT** Got it working,but now I'm getting a GDataXMLNode.h file not found error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you can't add the GData framework to an iOS project because it's only designed for Mac OSX. You must use GData as a linked library.

Answer (score 1):

Try add all GData framework header files into your project. (especially GDataXMLNode.h file)

Answer (score 0):

look this post http://intridea.com/blog/2010/12/28/a-visual-guide-to-creating-an-embeddable-framework-for-mac-osx

it resolve my problem.